# Why does 'rysnc' change file-system permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to use `rsync` to sync files from my laptop (`Ubuntu 14.04`) to an external disk. When connecting the disk I start the sync with the following command:

```
rsync -av --delete /home/alexander/10_Private /media/alexander/LACIESHARE/Backup
```

It starts fine, but later on every transfer faild because I do not have write permission on the disk any more; here part of the output of the `rysnc` command:

```
....
10_Private/Vodafone/contract.jpg
10_Private/Vodafone/letter2.pdf
rsync: mkstemp "/media/alexander/LACIESHARE/Backup/10_Private/Swiss/.Oeffnungszeiten.pdf.pKmrxs" failed: Read-only file system (30)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/alexander/LACIESHARE/Backup/10_Private/Swiss/COOP/.Adressaenderung.pdf.zCxEJn" failed: Read-only file system (30)
....
```

How is it possible that rsync suddenly changes the file-system of the external disk to 'read-only'? What is going on, and how to fix this behaviour?

During the sync, I have nothing done regarding the external disk; no other file copy, file access...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drive is probably mounted with the `errors=remount-ro` option, AND there are read or write errors while running the `rsync`.  That option causes the drive to be remounted as read-only if there are any read or write errors detected.

This could be caused by a bad connector or cable, bad port (e.g. USB or esata), or because the drive itself is failing.

In other words, it's probably a hardware fault.

Comment: This makes sense, but I cannot see this mounting option: `/dev/sdc1 on /media/alexander/LACIESHARE type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: `errors=remount-ro` is the default for FAT filesystems.  `man mount`, search for `FAT.*error`